# Ironic conductor dies as soon as it starts

Tags: openstack

I have installed `ironic standalone` on a vagrant `centos 7`box using `bifrost`.

The `ironic.conf` is as below:

```
[DEFAULT]
debug = True
# NOTE(TheJulia): Until Bifrost supports neutron or some other network
# configuration besides a flat network where bifrost orchustrates the
# control instead of ironic, noop is the only available network driver.
enabled_network_interfaces = noop
default_deploy_interface = direct
enabled_inspect_interfaces = no-inspect,inspector,ilo
default_inspect_interface = inspector
enabled_boot_interfaces = ilo-virtual-media,ilo-pxe
enabled_management_interfaces = ilo,ipmitool,ucsm
enabled_power_interfaces = ilo,ipmitool,ucsm
enabled_console_interfaces = ilo,no-console

enabled_hardware_types = ipmi,ilo,cisco-ucs-managed
enabled_drivers = agent_ipmitool,agent_ilo,agent_ucs,pxe_ipmitool,pxe_ilo

rabbit_userid = ironic
rabbit_password = aSecretPassword473z

auth_strategy = noauth


[pxe]
pxe_append_params = systemd.journald.forward_to_console=yes
pxe_config_template = $pybasedir/drivers/modules/ipxe_config.template
tftp_server = 10.0.15.10
tftp_root = /tftpboot
pxe_bootfile_name = undionly.kpxe
ipxe_enabled = true
ipxe_boot_script = /etc/ironic/boot.ipxe
tftp_master_path = /var/lib/ironic/master_images

[deploy]
http_url = http://10.0.15.10:8080/
http_root = /httpboot

[conductor]
clean_nodes = false
automated_clean = false

[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://ironic:aSecretPassword473z@localhost/ironic?charset=utf8

[dhcp]
dhcp_provider = none


[ilo]
use_web_server_for_images = true

[inspector]
enabled = true
auth_type=none
endpoint_override=http://127.0.0.1:5050


[service_catalog]
auth_type = none
endpoint_override = http://10.0.15.10:6385
```

I have also setup dhcp and tftp configurations for a pxe boot. But the ironic conductor keeps dying.

```
[root@mgmt group_vars]# systemctl restart ironic-conductor
[root@mgmt group_vars]# systemctl status ironic-conductor
● ironic-conductor.service - ironic-conductor service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ironic-conductor.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-27 07:34:29 UTC; 1s ago
 Main PID: 4264 (ironic-conducto)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ironic-conductor.service
           └─4264 /usr/bin/python2 /bin/ironic-conductor --config-file /etc/ironic/ironic.conf

Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_host = localhost log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_hosts = ['localhost:5672'] log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_interval_max = 30 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_login_method = AMQPLAIN log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_max_retries = 0 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Option "rabbit_password" from group "DEFAULT" is deprecated. Use option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit".
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be sile...nored in the future.
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_password = **** log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_port = 5672 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_qos_prefetch_count = 0 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@mgmt group_vars]# systemctl status ironic-conductor
● ironic-conductor.service - ironic-conductor service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ironic-conductor.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2018-06-27 07:34:33 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 4264 ExecStart=/bin/ironic-conductor --config-file /etc/ironic/ironic.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4264 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_host = localhost log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_hosts = ['localhost:5672'] log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_interval_max = 30 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_login_method = AMQPLAIN log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_max_retries = 0 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.255 4264 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Option "rabbit_password" from group "DEFAULT" is deprecated. Use option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit".
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 WARNING oslo_config.cfg [-] Option "rabbit_password" from group "oslo_messaging_rabbit" is deprecated for removal (Replaced by [DEFAULT]/transport_url).  Its value may be sile...nored in the future.
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_password = **** log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_port = 5672 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Jun 27 07:34:31 mgmt ironic-conductor[4264]: 2018-06-27 07:34:31.256 4264 DEBUG oslo_service.service [-] oslo_messaging_rabbit.rabbit_qos_prefetch_count = 0 log_opt_values /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py:2908
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

As soon as I restart it, it dies within seconds and I am not able to figure out why this happens.

```
ps aux | grep ironic
ironic     565  1.6  7.6 224256 18396 ?        Ss   09:59   0:44 /usr/bin/python2 /bin/ironic-inspector --config-file /etc/ironic-inspector/inspector.conf
ironic    5533 57.2 33.4 254396 80660 ?        Rs   10:44   0:02 /usr/bin/python2 /bin/ironic-api --config-file /etc/ironic/ironic.conf
ironic    5545  1.0 31.5 254396 76112 ?        S    10:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python2 /bin/ironic-api --config-file /etc/ironic/ironic.conf
```

Comment: Have you checked the full log at `/var/log/ironic/ironic-conductor.log` It might give you more clues. Please check it and report back if new hints appear.

Comment: there is no log inside /var/log/ironic. Is there some property to enable loggin?

Comment: what if you do `journalctl -u ironic-conductor --no-pager`, any hints?

Comment: that prints all the configurations set. does not show any errors.

Comment: Is there maybe any process hung? If you do `ps aux | grep ironic`, what do you see?

Comment: Ive added the ps aux response to the question

Comment: If you run `journalctl -u ironic-conductor -f` in one shell, and trigger a restart in another shell, do you see any additional output?

Comment: I tried that too. Doesnt show any errors. Anyways I reinstalled bifrost and its working now. Hopefully it wont die again